# In development mode .env variables are working, however once deployed to netlify they are showing as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, create-react-app, netlify

I have used create-react-app to build a web app and put the api keys in the .env file in the root folder of my project.

as shown below...

````
REACT_APP_EDAMAM_API_KEY=***********

REACT_APP_EDAMAM_APP_ID=*********```
````

however I'm receiving this error when the site is deployed to netlify...

```
Type Error: failed to fetch
```

and in the response header it says both the api_key and the app_id are undefined?

here is the api call

```
const fetchMyApi = async (searchQuery) => {
  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_EDAMAM_API_KEY;
  const APP_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_EDAMAM_APP_ID;

  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&q=`;

  const response = await fetch(url + searchQuery);

  const data = await response.json();

  return data.hits;
};

export default fetchMyApi;
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: see the docs: [Netlify: Build environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/) your .env file shouldn't be pushed to the repository (especially a public one!)  – you need to set the environment variables, with relevant privacy settings, in your Netlify project.

Comment: Finally!!! thank you so much this was the answer I was looking for after trying to work it out for days! lifesaver, thanks again!